# Postfix giving 5.1.1 error on an alias - how can I log/debug?

Tags: postfix

I have a simple alias in my `/etc/aliases` file that is failing. The alias is simply `support4` and it should point to `support@example.com`.

When I send a message to `support4@example.com`, it bounces with a 5.1.1 Address error.

The main `support@example.com` address works perfectly and can receive mail with no problems.

How can I log/debug what is going on?

Comment: Procmail does not handle incoming address validation. Did you mean Postfix? Or which mail server are you running?

Comment: @tripleee Thank you for your comment-- sorry, then I guess I mean postfix. That's what I'm running on my server. (Edited my question.) Didn't realize postfix was the program that processed the aliases in `/etc/aliases`.

Comment: Did you run `postmap /etc/aliases` after adding the alias?

Comment: I just tried that and I get a ton of: postmap: `warning: /etc/aliases, line 11: record is in "key: value" format; is this an alias file?` ...however, I have other aliases that work fine, and I've never used the `postmap /etc/aliases` command before. Usually I just edit /etc/aliases and then use `newaliases` and that does the job.

Comment: I also tried `postalias /etc/aliases` and while that command didn't give me an error messages, it didn't fix the problem, either.